# What method i can use for handle this problems

Tags: javascript

i have found some code php, MySQL work with checkbox.. when tick a checkbox the table column has disappear..but what i need is when i tick a checkbox it will show the table column.. i got some code for that but all of them show when tick it will disappear.. so, have anyone can help me..

HTML...

```
<form id="search" name="search" action="index3.php" method="post" class="search">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="product" id="product" size="18" placeholder="Search Product"/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Search" />
        </p>
        <p>Location :
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_8" value="kluang" />
          Kluang&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_9" value="kl" />
          KL&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_10" value="meru" />
          Meru</p>
        <p>Grading :
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_11" value="grade1" />
          1&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_12" value="grade2" />
          2&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_13" value="grade3" />
          3</p>
        <p>Status : 
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_" value="grade1" /> 
          Available&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_2" value="grade2" />
          Reserve&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_3" value="grade3" />
          Clear Stock</p>
        <p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="showcol" id="col_14" value="palletno" />
          Pallet No </p>
      </form>
```

js code for hidden n show column

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Checkbox click
    $(".showcol").click(function(){

        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("_");
        var colno = splitid[1];
        var checked = true;

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            checked = true;
        }else{
            checked = false;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(checked){
                $('#emp_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                $('#emp_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
            } else{
                $('#emp_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                $('#emp_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
            }

        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking....

Comment: i need when checkbox is checked it will show a column table i want.. if unchecked it will be hidden

Comment: Isn't that what your code is doing? You should be listening to change event, not click event. Also not sure why you have a 1.5 second delay

Comment: can u provide suitable code for that or give me example where i need change

Comment: wrong tag, your code is not PHP, but HTML tag.

Comment: What is the problem? I do not know what your issue is. Does the code above not work.

Comment: yeah abed but i using in php statement..
epascarello the problem is when i check the checkbox..column number related with checked will be hidden..i need when i check the checkbox column will be show..

Comment: Where is this element? `#emp_table`  You also have several Javascript errors, such as ` var id = this.id` whould be `var id = $(this).prop('id');`

Comment: You also changed all but one of these  `class="showcol"` to `class="hidecol"` but never updated the event  `$(".showcol").click...)` so it only triggers on the last checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot.

I cleaned up a lot of the Javascript.  I don't see the point for the timeout so I commented that out. Also as you didn't have that table where the columns are in your post, I simplified it some and just did one.

I also wrapped the label in a label tag.  This may seem a simple thing, but the reason is that if you set the `for` attribute to match the `id` of the input, then clicking the label passes it on to the input, which is really nice for usability.

To add the other ones back in just copy the one I did, and update the inputs `id` and the labels `for` attribute to match the index of the column you wish to hide / show.

As you want `unchecked/hidden` and checked/show`  You can either hide the column by default ( as I did ) or you an make the checkbox checked by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Checkbox click
    $(".hidecol").change(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var id = self.prop('id');
        var colno = id.split("_")[1];

  //      setTimeout(function(){
            if(self.is(':checked')){
                $('#emp_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                $('#emp_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
            } else{
                $('#emp_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                $('#emp_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();;
            }

 //       }, 1500);
    });
});
```

```html
<style type="text/css" >
#emp_table
{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px
}

#emp_table td, #emp_table th
{
  padding : 0px 10px;
  border : 1px dashed grey;
}
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search" name="search" action="index3.php" method="post" class="search">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="product" id="product" size="18" placeholder="Search Product"/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Search" />
        </p>
        <p>
          Location :
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" id="col_2" value="test" />
         <label for="col_2" >Test&nbsp;Dynamic</label>
        <p>
      </form>
      
      
      <table id="emp_table">
          <tr>
              <th>Fixed</th>
              <th style="display:none;" >Dynamic</th>
          </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>Fixed Value</td>
              <td style="display:none;" >Dynamic Value</td>
         </tr>      
      </table>
```

**UPDATE** if you don't have jquery included, it wont work.  To include jquery do this in the `<head>` of your html page

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title></title> 
         <!-- other stuff -->

         <!-- copy the line below into the head of you page -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Did you click `Run code snippet` ?

Comment: yes i did run smooth..but when i use that code n make a change n then run into browser using localhost, nothing happen

Comment: Does it run without making a change?

Comment: also, you should get used to using the debug window of the browser usually `F12`, then it will show you in `console` errors and anything you put `console.log(var)`. ( except for IE < 10 )

Comment: same when i move your code into my pc n run..it doesnt work.. when click test dynamic nothing happen

Comment: which one should i take?

Comment: see my update, I used `2.x` something in the answer.  For this I don't think it matters much, it's pretty basic.

Comment: i have include jquery framework but still nothing happen